# My flutter android studio terminal doesn't work

Tags: windows, android-studio, flutter, terminal

If I write something such as flutter doctor inside the terminal, it saids ('flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)and it doesn't work.Is there a specific place you should put the flutter file? Is there something you should add in the Enviroment variables?
(Im using a window 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to add flutter to your environment path

1. On the Windows desktop, right-click My Computer.
2. In the pop-up menu, click Properties.
3. In the System Properties window, click the Advanced tab, and then click Environment Variables.
4. In the System Variables window, edit Path;
5. Add your <Flutter_Path>/bin
6. Restart your IDE and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing the PATH variables.

Follow these steps:

1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
2. Click the Advanced system settings link.
3. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit.
4. In the Edit System Variable window, add C:\Windows\System32
   separated by a ;. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking
   OK.
5. Restart your computer.

Now run flutter doctor